# C/C++: libcurl + extended ASCII chars = bad Google Translation API result

Tags: c++, c, libcurl, google-translation-api

I'm trying to use the Google Translation API with libcurl in my C/C++ program, but I get a bad result whenever I translate something with extended ASCII. For example, translating "nuß" to English (German word for "nut"). Note that ß is an extended ASCII character (0xDF), you don't need Unicode to write it.

### "nuß" → English in Chrome

When I open this URL in Chrome, it successfully translates to "nut":
[https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&sl=de&tl=en&dt=t&q=nuß](https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&sl=de&tl=en&dt=t&q=nu%C3%9F)

```
[[["nut","nuß",null,null,2]],null,"de"
```

### "nuß" → English in my C/C++ program

When I use the same URL from my C/C++ program, it erroneously translates to "nu?"

```
[[["nu?","nu?",null,null,0]],null,"de"
```

Here is my program:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#define CURL_STATICLIB
#include "curl/curl.h"

int main() {
    CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();

    if (curl) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&sl=de&tl=en&dt=t&q=nuß");
        curl_easy_perform(curl);
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Same thing happens if I change the end of the URL to `nu%DF` instead of `nuß`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, I needed to encode the ß as `%C3%9F`. I was doing the "percent sign encoding" with the ASCII code for ß (`%DF`) whereas I needed to use the UTF-8 code for it.

Comment: For future readers it might be useful to know why this works. You might add a few details about the used encoding and why it is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try doing [curl_easy_escape](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_escape.html) ? When you have non-ascii char set it is probably a good idea to escape the string first. Please note this doesn't care about character encodings (in your case utf8). So you need to first convert the encoding using some of the standard ways [like this for C++](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt) Or [iconv](https://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/) for C/C++.

Comment: I did try escaping it to `nu%DF` with the same result. ß is an extended ASCII character and doesn't require Unicode so I wouldn't think I would need to convert anything.